# Size of a Canvas in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

In a C# WPF application, I have a section:

```
<Canvas>
    <Image Source="myverybigimage.tif"/>
</Canvas>
```

In the code, I try to get the size of the Canvas, and expect it to be about 5000px wide, due to the big image it contains.

However, I've looked at the Canvas properties:

```
ActualWidth:  (just the size of the Window, around 1000)
RenderSize.Width: (also the size of the Window, around 1000)            
Width: NaN
MaxWidth: Infinity
MinWidth: Zero
```

Given a Canvas that contains an element larger than the window, is there a way to get the full size that the Canvas should / would be if it were fully drawn?

Comment: Have you verified the image's width conforms to your expectations? Also, how/when are you measuring it - are you ensuring you wait for the image to fully load and the canvas and the wpf Layout engine to catch up?

Comment: Yes this is expected. The ActualWidth/Height are based on the RenderSize. The RenderSize is based on the size at which the element is arranged. I'm guessing the parent element is 1000px or you set the MinWidth/Height to 1000. A canvas is designed to measure its children with infinity and arrange it based in that desired size. You won't be able to tell from it that it's children are bigger. Maybe you can try using the VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds.

Comment: @MDR:  I'm quite confident the image is the size I expect, and behaves as I expect when it is not inside a Canvas. (but I need it in a Canvas or similar container for the next feature in the program).  The Image is fully displayed, and the layout is fully completed.

Comment: @AndrewS:  `VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds` seems to do exactly what I need.  Thanks!  If you make it an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608740%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).